# Generating SSH key in git bash, i can't get git agent

Tags: ssh, git-bash, ssh-keys, permission-denied, ssh-agent

When I am trying to generate SSH key in git bash, I can't get git agent when we run this command

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

then I will get this error

```
unix_listener: cannot listen on path /tmp/ssh-xoEnzGUu8XxU/agent.1287: Permission denied
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184401/6309), that could be a permission issue for writing the SSH socket.
Check the permission associated to `/tmp` or `/tmp/ssh-xoEnzGUu8XxU/agent.1287`

Or try:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh-agent.$$)
```

The socket will be written in your $HOME instead of `/tmp`: no more permission issue.